# Common syntax in MySQL and MSSQL for IF INSERT ELSE UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, insert-update

I have a PHP 7.3 project which connects via PDO to a **MySQL** database or a **MSSQL** database, depending on being run on Linux or Windows.

I want to insert a new values into a table, if the unique value is not yet in that table. If it is already in the table, I want to update the non-unique values.

I searched a lot of docs and SO posts, also, but I couldn't find a syntax, which does that **in one query for both database types**.

SQL Server query:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM failed_logins_ip_address WHERE ip_address = 'xxx'))
  BEGIN
    UPDATE failed_logins_ip_address
    SET attempts_count = attempts_count + 1, attempt_datetime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE ip_address = 'xxx'
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO failed_logins_ip_address (ip_address, attempts_count, attempt_datetime)
    VALUES ('xxx', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  END
```

MySQL query:

```
INSERT INTO failed_logins_ip_address (ip_address, attempts_count, attempt_datetime)
  VALUES ('xxx', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY
  UPDATE attempts_count = attempts_count + 1, attempt_datetime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

'ip_addess' column is unique, and the table structure is identical for both MSSQL and MySQL.

**Is there a syntax, which can do an IF INSERT ELSE UPDATE in both database types?**

---

Yes, I do (PDO) parameter binding, xxx is just to shorten the code snippet.

Yes, I could use identical syntax if I did it in two queries (first select, then insert or update) but I want to avoid (hopefully) unnecessary queries.

No, I do not want to insert every login attempt so I do not need the update anymore because I do not need this data.

If the REPLACE approach would work: this does not update, it deletes and inserts, which I also do not want.

**My current solution**: I check in PHP for the current database type and switch/case the query strings. It is clean but one string is even less smelly ;-)

---

UPDATE:

I changed the MSSQL query around: from of IF NOT EXISTS TO IF EXISTS to improve the efficiency. UPDATE will occur a lot more often than INSERT, so in most of the cases, only the first (sub)query will be executed.

Comment: You search a lot and you didn't find anything about `MERGE`?

Comment: No, @Sami I did not find merge. I'll check now.

Comment: @Sami `MERGE` is not there in MySQL. I think OP is trying to find a common function between MySQL and SQL Server.

Comment: @Sami the EXISTS syntax is different in MSSQL and MYSQL!

Comment: There is no common way to do this in both MySQL and SQL Server AFAIK.

Comment: Instead of looking for common syntax, why don't you create stored procedures on both with the same name?

Comment: @jasie You can create Stored Procedures (Routines) using the respective syntax of MySQL / SQL server, and define it into the server at once. You can ensure that both the stored procedure has same name. Now, I am not much familiar of SQL Server, but it seems that it supports [`CALL ..`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-stored-procedures/calling-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017) statement, which is also supported by MySQL. So you can simply call the stored procedure with the common name

Comment: Thanks, @MadhurBhaiya I was not aware of Stored Procedures - I will look into it!

Comment: Just had this idea: would batch queries be an in-between solution between one query and two complete separate queries, that allows for the same syntax? (batch select then insert or update)

Comment: If store procedures don't work wouldn't a simple `if` in PHP to determine the OS type let you use the appropriate syntax? Certainly seems a lot cleaner and easier and more obvious for the next person that has to maintain the code.

Comment: @Dave As I wrote in my question (last paragraph), this PHP if (in form of switch/case) is my current solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper, I found this post by a Derek Dieter, which describes **how to replace SQL Server's IF EXISTS ELSE by WHERE EXISTS**:

https://sqlserverplanet.com/optimization/avoiding-if-else-by-using-where-exists

The **WHERE EXISTS syntax seems to be the same in [MySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-exists/) and [MSSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**.

Derek Dieter's example, with IF EXSISTS:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM customer_totals WHERE cust_id = @cust_id)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO customer_totals
(
cust_id,
order_amt
)
SELECT
cust_id = @cust_id
,order_amt = @order_amt
END
ELSE

UPDATE customer
SET order_amt = order_amt + @order_amt
WHERE cust_id = @cust_id

END
```

Derek Dieter's example, with WHERE EXISTS:

```
INSERT INTO customer_totals
(
cust_id,
order_amt
)
SELECT TOP 1 — important since we’re not constraining any records
cust_id = @cust_id
,order_amt = @order_amt
FROM customer_totals ct
WHERE NOT EXISTS — this replaces the if statement
(
SELECT 1
FROM customer_totals
WHERE cust_id = @cust_id
)

SET @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT — return back the rows that got inserted

UPDATE customer
SET order_amt = order_amt + @order_amt
WHERE @rowcount = 0
AND cust_id = @cust_id — if no rows were inserted, the cust_id must exist, so update
```

I still have to test it, though, in MySQL. I'll update this post and add the code, if it works.

Comment: Don't know about MySQL, but using WHERE EXISTS isn't going to let you choose between doing an INSERT and an UPDATE in SQL Server.   You would have to use 2  queries to replace your current IF EXISTS logic.

Comment: @TabAlleman Check Derek's code transformation. It seems he found a way but I have little hope this would work in MySQL...

Comment: It's true that his code only uses EXISTS once, but instead it always runs two queries: an INSERT and an UPDATE, instead of using IF to determine which single query to run.  I doubt this is "better" in any way than what you were already doing.   By the way I also doubt that you will find any syntax that does this in both MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PHP, then you are calling the code through an interface.  You can do the following:

1. Create a unique index on `ip_address`.
2. Attempt to insert a new row.  This will fail if the row already exists.
3. If the insert fails (particularly with a duplicate key error), then update the existing row.

However, your goal of trying to have the same code in both databases is . . . just not going to work very well.  The two databases are rather different.  Perhaps you should consider constructing stored procedures in each database to do what you want and then calling those stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote, ip_adress has already unique index. And no disrespect, but I also wrote, I do not want to do two queries. I already have a clean workaround solution (also described), and I do not see, how your proposed solution adds anything new, no offense :-/

Comment: Also, what you describe in 2. and 3. can either be done in one query (exists/duplicate) or in two separate (first insert, then (eventually update) - your text makes not clear what exactly you mean - at least not to me, sry.

Comment: @jasie unless you use the on duplicate key update, you will do two queries anyway. Subqueries are separate queries. This solution is the most straightforward of all solutions and insert / update syntax is common between the two products.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for poiting that out, indeed, the if else has subqueries. BUT the else is not always executed. I should switch, though, from IF NOT to IF as the UPDATE is more likely than the INSERT as it will occur much more often - thanks for that inspiration. Anyway, due to this limitation, it is still less efficient to ALWAYS execute two queries (first SELECT, then INSERT or UPDATE).

Comment: Gordon's solution does not require a select. You run an insert and in case it fails, you run the update.

Comment: Yes, @Shadow but UPDATE occurs way more often than INSERT - not very efficient. Could I turn Gordon's approach around: try to update and insert if that fails?

Comment: @jasie yes you can swap the logic and check if the update affected any rows and insert if it did not affect any.